# Pandas- Indexing error using sklearn and numpy for ML

Tags: pandas, indexing

File "C:/Users/hello/PycharmProject/LR/Linear Reg.py", line 9, in 
    data = data[["d2s packet rate", "s2d packet rate", "s2d inter time", "d2s packets"]]
  File "C:\Users\hello\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2806, in **getitem**
    indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
  File "C:\Users\hello\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1552, in _get_listlike_indexer
    keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
  File "C:\Users\hello\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1645, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
KeyError: "['s2d inter time'] not in index"

How can I solve this error?

I'm new to coding and machine learning.
I'm selecting a few attributes from the given dataset but it gives error when attributes are out of order, while in the order it works fine. Above is the error shown after running the code.

Your answers/solutions/help is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please post the minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

data = pd.read_csv("normal-train.csv", sep=",")

data = data[["d2s packet rate", "s2d packet rate", "s2d inter time", "d2s packets"]]
print(data.head())

Comment: this is just the basic code. I'm using a normal network dataset. When the labels used in the sequence it works fine but when skipped it throws the error as shown above.

Comment: Seems like column 's2d inter time' doesn't exist. Moreover, please format the question properly. I am sorry to say this, but people don't have time to read the question, then the comments and finally format your question. As long as it's not well formatted and well asked, you may not receive an answer. Further, it may lead to down-voting of the question.